# File Upload(Image and Video) using Akamai's NetStorage CMS API in C#

Tags: c#, image, rest, video, akamai

I am trying to use the Akamai's NetStorage CMS API for uploading images and videos using asp.net fileupload and looking for any C# REST API(Controller) where we can call NetStorage Upload method.

Looked in their documentation and googled for AKamai CMS API file upload C#, but returned with no luck.

I know how to upload a txt file using Akamai upload method and write content to that text file, but i am looking for something like:

1. User selects a file
2. Use that file and upload to Akamai file storage
3. And when user edits that image(example to rename image title or author info) , get the image from Akamai storage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NetStorageKit for C# here:

https://github.com/akamai-open/NetStorageKit-C-Sharp